Given a first row with even valued length n construct a matrix which is both symmetric and persymmetric
For example if n = 4,
row = {1,5,6,7}

Construct the matrix
 mat = {{1,5,6,7},{5,1,7,6},{6,7,1,5},{7,6,5,1}}

$\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 1 & 5 & 6 & 7 \\
 5 & 1 & 7 & 6 \\
 6 & 7 & 1 & 5 \\
 7 & 6 & 5 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)$
Test for symmetry
mat == Transpose[mat] (* True *)

Test for persymmetry
mat == Reverse/@Transpose[Reverse/@mat] (* True *)

I need a method for arbitrary even n lengths.

Why this particular matrix mat when there are infinitely many that satisfy both of your equations and have the same first row?

@azerbajdzan All rows must some permutation of the same values.

You did not mention it in your question. But even if it is permutation of the first row there are still few possibilities.

Not as nice as @lericr's answer, but here's a version that avoids SubsetMap, and should work in 11.3
MakeSymAndPersym[list_] := 
 Module[{len, subMatrix, oneBlockRow, halfMat, indexMat},
   len = Length[list]/2;
   
   subMatrix = len*IdentityMatrix[len] - 1;
   oneBlockRow = Most /@ {-Reverse[subMatrix], subMatrix};
   
   halfMat = 
    Accumulate@
     ArrayFlatten[{List /@ Partition[Range[2 len], len], oneBlockRow}];
   indexMat = 
    ArrayFlatten[{{halfMat}, {Reverse /@ (Reverse@halfMat)}}];
   
   Map[Part[list, #] &, indexMat, {-1}]
   
   ] /; EvenQ[Length[list]]

This probably can still be optimized a lot.

Perfect, thank you.

Your large n image result is very interesting!

This can probably be made more elegant:
MakeSymAndPersym[list_] :=
  With[
  {len = Length[list]/2},
  MapAt[Reverse, List /@ Range[-len, -1]]@*
  SubsetMap[Reverse, -len ;;]@*
  NestList[SubsetMap[RotateRight, -len ;;]@*SubsetMap[RotateLeft, ;; len], Length[list] - 1]@
   list] /; EvenQ[Length[list]]

MakeSymAndPersym[list]
(* {{1, 5, 6, 7}, 
    {5, 1, 7, 6}, 
    {6, 7, 1, 5}, 
    {7, 6, 5, 1}} *)

Update
I think this is compatible with version 11:
MakeSymAndPersym2[list_] :=
  With[
    {halfLength = Length[list]/2},
    With[
      {seed = TakeDrop[list, halfLength]},
      With[
        {quad1 = NestList[RotateLeft, seed[[1]], halfLength - 1],
         quad2 = NestList[RotateRight, seed[[-1]], halfLength - 1]},
        With[
          {quad3 = Map[Reverse, quad2, {0, 1}],
           quad4 = Map[Reverse, quad1, {0, 1}]},
          Flatten[{{quad1, quad2}, {quad3, quad4}}, {{1, 3}, {2, 4}}]]]]] /; EvenQ[Length[list]]


I have Mathematica 11.3, I get the error "NestList::argrx: NestList called with 2 arguments; 3 arguments are expected."

Oh, and 11.3 does not know SubsetMap, can you provide a definition or an alternative, please?

Completely unrelated, but the image made by this using Range[n] for large n as the starting row looks really cool! (MakeSymAndPersym@Range[1000]) // Rescale // Image

@PhillipDukes Please see update.

Using GroupMultiplicationTable :
row = {1, 5, 6, 7};
len = Length@row;
perm = 
  Cycles@
   Apply[{RotateRight@Reverse@#, #2} &, Partition[Range@len, len/2]];
gmt = 
  GroupMultiplicationTable@
   PermutationGroup@
    {perm, PermutationCycles[Reverse@Range@len], InversePermutation@perm};
mat = Map[row[[#]] &, gmt, {2}] ;
mat // TeXForm

$
\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 1 & 5 & 6 & 7 \\
 5 & 1 & 7 & 6 \\
 6 & 7 & 1 & 5 \\
 7 & 6 & 5 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$
